# Gitlab Omnibus 500 error when adding domain to Outbound Requests in Admin Area

Tags: gitlab

We're hosting the gitlab omnibus application in an AWS account and running version 13.9.1-ee. I'm trying to update the outbound requests to allow us to append an internal webhook to a project. When visiting the Admin Area -> Setttings -> Network -> Outbound Requests, add an entry i.e example.com click save changes I get a http 500.

Checking the /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log on the server I get the below error message. It appears to be a OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError type error, but very little diagnostic information is given.

Has anyone seen this before? If someone could respond that would be extremely helpful for us!

Thanks,
Matt

```
    {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "path": "/admin/application_settings/network",
    "format": "html",
    "controller": "Admin::ApplicationSettingsController",
    "action": "network",
    "status": 500,
    "time": "2021-03-17T12:25:34.764Z",
    "params": [
        {
            "key": "utf8",
            "value": "✓"
        },
        {
            "key": "_method",
            "value": "patch"
        },
        {
            "key": "authenticity_token",
            "value": "[FILTERED]"
        },
        {
            "key": "application_setting",
            "value": {
                "allow_local_requests_from_web_hooks_and_services": "1",
                "allow_local_requests_from_system_hooks": "1",
                "outbound_local_requests_allowlist_raw": "example.com",
                "dns_rebinding_protection_enabled": "1"
            }
        }
    ],
    "remote_ip": "XXX",
    "user_id": 14,
    "username": "matt.gawne",
    "ua": "Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36",
    "correlation_id": "01F102BZ7Z3GWVT2EKWMWA6BKA",
    "meta.user": "matt.gawne",
    "meta.caller_id": "Admin::ApplicationSettingsController#network",
    "meta.remote_ip": "XXX",
    "meta.feature_category": "not_owned",
    "redis_calls": 6,
    "redis_duration_s": 0.001715,
    "redis_read_bytes": 1031,
    "redis_write_bytes": 1122,
    "redis_cache_calls": 5,
    "redis_cache_duration_s": 0.001346,
    "redis_cache_read_bytes": 848,
    "redis_cache_write_bytes": 247,
    "redis_shared_state_calls": 1,
    "redis_shared_state_duration_s": 0.000369,
    "redis_shared_state_read_bytes": 183,
    "redis_shared_state_write_bytes": 875,
    "db_count": 30,
    "db_write_count": 0,
    "db_cached_count": 25,
    "cpu_s": 0.038537,
    "queue_duration_s": 0.010149,
    "exception.class": "OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError",
    "exception.message": "",
    "exception.backtrace": [
        "app/services/application_settings/update_service.rb:50:in `update_settings'",
        "lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:160:in `block in update_settings'",
        "lib/gitlab/metrics/method_call.rb:27:in `measure'",
        "lib/gitlab/metrics/instrumentation.rb:160:in `update_settings'",
        "app/services/application_settings/update_service.rb:12:in `execute'",
        "ee/app/services/ee/application_settings/update_service.rb:22:in `execute'",
        "app/controllers/admin/application_settings_controller.rb:263:in `perform_update'",
        "app/controllers/admin/application_settings_controller.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ApplicationSettingsController>'",
        "ee/lib/gitlab/ip_address_state.rb:10:in `with'",
        "ee/app/controllers/ee/application_controller.rb:44:in `set_current_ip_address'",
        "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:482:in `set_current_admin'",
        "lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'",
        "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:473:in `set_session_storage'",
        "lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:73:in `with_locale'",
        "lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:79:in `with_user_locale'",
        "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:467:in `set_locale'",
        "lib/gitlab/error_tracking.rb:52:in `with_context'",
        "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:532:in `sentry_context'",
        "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:460:in `block in set_current_context'",
        "lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:56:in `block in use'",
        "lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:56:in `use'",
        "lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:22:in `with_context'",
        "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:451:in `set_current_context'",
        "lib/gitlab/metrics/elasticsearch_rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:33:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `block in call'",
        "lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:56:in `run'",
        "lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:17:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:19:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:21:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:172:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:50:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_malformed_strings.rb:21:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:21:in `call'",
        "config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:11:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:76:in `call'",
        "lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'"
    ],
    "db_duration_s": 0.0033,
    "view_duration_s": 0.0,
    "duration_s": 0.03183
}
```